# How to get consecutive lot number based on a range?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

```
LotNumber
1065
1026
95092
95090
95089
95088
85087
95086
95085
95084
95083
95082
95081
```

How should my SQL query look to return consecutive lot number based on a range (first match).

E.g. return 3 in range, (95090, 95089, 95088)
return 5 in range (95086, 95085, 95084, 95083, 95082)

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated variation of the gaps-and-island problem, since:

- you want all the elments in a group (not only the start and end)
- you want only the elements in the first group that satisfies the condition

The following query does what you expect:

```
select lotNumber
from (
    select 
        lotNumber,
        cnt,
        dense_rank() over(order by grp) rn
    from (
        select 
            lotNumber,
            grp,
            count(*) over(partition by grp) cnt
        from (
            select 
                lotNumber,
                sum(case when lotNumber = lagLotNumber - 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
                    over(order by id) grp
            from (
                select
                    id,
                    lotNumber, 
                    lag(lotNumber) over(order by id) lagLotNumber
                from mytable
            ) t
        ) t
    ) t
    where cnt >= 3
) t
where rn = 1
```

Clause `where cnt >= 3` can be used to control the target length of the consecutive numbers.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pvNGzBKUxKabeR7R9UmSqA/0)**

```
| lotnumber |
| --------- |
| 95090     |
| 95089     |
| 95088     |
```

---

**Step by step Explanations**

To start with, this can only be solved *if* a column exists that can be used to order the records (in sql tables, records are by default unordered). I assume that such a column exists and is called `id`. Here is the dataset:

```
| lotnumber | id  |
| --------- | --- |
| 1065      | 1   |
| 1026      | 2   |
| 95092     | 3   |
| 95090     | 4   |
| 95089     | 5   |
| 95088     | 6   |
| 85087     | 7   |
| 95086     | 8   |
| 95085     | 9   |
| 95084     | 10  |
| 95083     | 11  |
| 95082     | 12  |
| 95081     | 13  |
```

1) The first step consists in recovering the previous `lotNumber` of each record. For this, we use `lag()`.

```
select
    id,
    lotNumber, 
    lag(lotNumber) over(order by id) lagLotNumber
from mytable

| id  | lotnumber | laglotnumber |
| --- | --------- | ------------ |
| 1   | 1065      |              |
| 2   | 1026      | 1065         |
| 3   | 95092     | 1026         |
| 4   | 95090     | 95092        |
...
```

2) Then, we use a cumulative sum to put records in groups where lot numbers are consecutive. When two records are not consecutive, a new group starts:

```
select 
    lotNumber,
    sum(case when lotNumber = lagLotNumber - 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(order by id) grp
from (
    ... above query ...
) t

| lotnumber | grp |
| --------- | --- |
| 1065      | 1   |
| 1026      | 2   |
| 95092     | 3   |
| 95090     | 4   |
| 95089     | 4   |
| 95088     | 4   |
| 85087     | 5   |
| 95086     | 6   |
| 95085     | 6   |
| 95084     | 6   |
| 95083     | 6   |
| 95082     | 6   |
| 95081     | 6   |
```

3) The next step consists in counting how many records we have in each group, with a window count

```
select 
    lotNumber,
    grp,
    count(*) over(partition by grp) cnt
from (
    ... above query ...
) t;

| lotnumber | grp | cnt |
| --------- | --- | --- |
| 1065      | 1   | 1   |
| 1026      | 2   | 1   |
| 95092     | 3   | 1   |
| 95090     | 4   | 3   |
| 95089     | 4   | 3   |
| 95088     | 4   | 3   |
| 85087     | 5   | 1   |
| 95086     | 6   | 6   |
| 95085     | 6   | 6   |
| 95084     | 6   | 6   |
| 95083     | 6   | 6   |
| 95082     | 6   | 6   |
| 95081     | 6   | 6   |
```

4) With this information at hand, we can now filter on the groups that have at least the target number of consecutive records. At the same time, we rank groups by ascending lot number. Filtering condition `where cnt >= 3`  can be changed as needed to control the target number of consecutive records.

Here, we have two groups with at least 3 consecutive numbers:

```
select 
    lotNumber,
    cnt,
    dense_rank() over(order by grp) rn
from (
    ... above query ...
) t
where cnt >= 3;

| lotnumber | cnt | rn  |
| --------- | --- | --- |
| 95090     | 3   | 1   |
| 95089     | 3   | 1   |
| 95088     | 3   | 1   |
| 95086     | 6   | 2   |
| 95085     | 6   | 2   |
| 95084     | 6   | 2   |
| 95083     | 6   | 2   |
| 95082     | 6   | 2   |
| 95081     | 6   | 2   |
```

5) The last step consists in just filtering on the top record in each group.

```
select lotNumber
from (
    ... above query ...
) t
where rn = 1

| lotnumber |
| --------- |
| 95090     |
| 95089     |
| 95088     |
```

Comment: I might have overcomplicated this and I am willing to see if someone comes up with a simpler solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value `n`, you can use `lead()` for this.  To get the first in the series:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lead(lotnumber, <n> - 1) over (order by lotnumber) as n_after
      from t
     ) t
where n_after - lotnumber = <n> - 1;
```

Postgres allows the `lag()`/`lead()` offset to be zero, so this even works for n = 1.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d86b9cb85feca8fe1382f5bf057890e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Perfect solution gordon even I was wondering could be lot simpler with lead() or lag() to check if the value is consecutive or not

Comment: With OP's sample data, this works with `n=3`, but seemingly not with `n=6`: see [this fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pvNGzBKUxKabeR7R9UmSqA/4)

Comment: @GMB . . . There was (at least what I consider to be) a typo in the answer.  It give very reasonable results regardless of the value of "n".

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number to order by

```
   Select 
          LotNumber, 
          row_number() over 
      (partition by 

 Substr(3,length(LotNumber),lotnumber) 
        order by 
        LotNumber ) rn
       from table  order by rn;
```